# how to set button disable in certain condition in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import PhoneInput, { formatPhoneNumber, formatPhoneNumberIntl, isValidPhoneNumber } from 'react-phone-number-input';

const [fields, setFields] = React.useState([{ value: null }]);

<PhoneInput
  id="phoneNumbers1"
  type="text"
  placeholder="Enter phone number "
  value={field.value || ""}
  defaultCountry="US"
  international
  name="phoneNumbers"
  error={disable}
  autoComplete='off'
  onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
  onChange={(e) => handleChange(idx, e)}
  onClick={() => setIndex(idx)}
/>
<button
  type="button"
  hidden={fields.length > 1}
  data-value={fields.length}
  disabled={!fields[0]?.value && !(isValidPhoneNumber(fields[0]?.value ||''||fields.length<10))}
  onClick={() => handleAdd()}
>
  + Phone
</button>
```

Inside button inside disable property if I try to give condition that button is disabled until user give 10 digit phone number with condition `field.length < 10`. It throws an error "TypeError: A text for parsing must be a string." What should be the condition inside disable attribute that until user give 10 digit phone number button should disable?

Comment: You can do ```String(fields).length```. This will always provide you with the length weather it exists or not

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hvxyc9 refer this

Comment: @DoubleH Code edits are ok, fixing whitespace and readability issues, etc... but the code should maintain the OPs original intent. Don't entirely change the logic.

Comment: function handleChange(i, event) {
    if (event) {

      const values = [...fields];
      values[i].value = event;
      setFields(v => values);
      //alert(JSON.stringify(values))
      formik.setFieldValue("phoneNumbers", { primaryPhone: values[0]?.value, secondaryPhone: values[1]?.value });
    }
  }      i have handlechange function in this way how should i replace this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I had to guess here, it seems `isValidPhoneNumber` may be expecting a string value, but if `fields[0]?.value` is falsey, and `''` is obviously falsey, the boolean `fields.length < 10` value is passed. I suspect you want this last condition outside of the `isValidPhoneNumber` validator function. I also suspect you want to check the length of the value, not the length of the fields array.

```
disabled={
  !isValidPhoneNumber(fields[0]?.value || "") ||
  fields[0]?.value?.length < 10
}
```

[image: Edit how-to-set-button-disable-in-certain-condition-in-react]

Comment: I've seen this a few times, but what does the shorthand notation in `fields[0]?.value` mean? Searching for the web doesn't give great results.

Comment: @Alan search for optional chaining operator

Comment: @SougataMukherjee Yes, `?.` is the [Optional Chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), useful for accessing into potentially null/undefined object properties (*and much more! *). "Shorthand" for `fields[0] && fields[0].value`.

Comment: yes sir previously i was bit confuse about the conditional operator but it ok

Answer (score 1):

I think the last condition is checking the length of array instead the length of the first value of the fields array i.e. `fields[0].value`.

Try to use

`disabled={!fields[0]?.value && !(isValidPhoneNumber(fields[0]?.value ||''||fields[0]?.value.length<10))}`